# Infinite loop on jboss7 when have a database exception

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I have a maven project, where I have used ejb6 and jboss 7 application server. When there is an exception related to database activity, the jboss log enters into an infinite loop, as a result the processor and the memory usage increases to 100%.

For example, if I try to retrieve one object but there are two objects in the result, I have an exception of unique result, but instead of printing once, the exception continues to be printed.

In my github I have my application with this problem.: https://github.com/alanj2diniz/ejb-loop-jboss-7

[Removed, external link has no relevance here]

Comment: You should extract the specific bit of code that's causing the problem and paste it here. Most folks will not have the time (or inclination to visit some other site to look for code and debug your problems..)

Comment: ejb6? What is that future technology? In any case extracting a specific piece of code is not going to be easy since this sounds like a very global issue. Apparently when an exception is caused, the reaction to that exception goes loopy; something I haven't ever seen yet. Which exact version of JBoss is being used here? JBoss 7.0 ? 7.1.1 ? 7.2 ?